# Set opacity to all tiles except for the one selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I noticed that there were a couple questions that were similar to this one, but not the same exactly.  I am using `ng-repeat` to show all of the uploaded images I have.  I can click on one and it will become the default picture.  I want the image that is clicked to look normal while all others have an `overlay`.  I tried setting `$('overlay').hide()` in my `selectImage` function, but that would only remove the overlay from my HTML on the first image.  Any ideas on how I can do this?

HTML

```
<!-- PHOTOS -->
      <div class="uploads-section" style="width: 100%;">
        <md-grid-list md-cols="3" md-row-height="1:1" md-gutter="8px" style="padding-top: 10px;">
          <md-grid-tile md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="1">
            <div style="background-color: #3F454b; padding: 30px; cursor: pointer; height: 100%; width: 100%;" class="upload-tile no-outline" layout="column" layout-align="center start" ng-click="uploadImage('photo')">
              <md-icon style="color: #FFFFFF; width: 40px; height: 40px;" md-svg-icon="images/upload.png"></md-icon>
              <p class="action-link" style="margin: 0; color: #FFFFFF;">UPLOAD</p>
            </div>
          </md-grid-tile>
          <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="photo in org.attachments | filter:{type:'photo'}" md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="1" style="opacity: .5;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden;" class="attachment-tile no-outline" layout="row" layout-align="center center" ng-click="selectImage($event, photo)">
              <!-- <p class="m1">Loading...</p> -->
              <img attachment-src="{{ photo.path | ThumbnailFilter }}" default-src="images/no_img.png" style="cursor: pointer; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;">
            </div>
          </md-grid-tile>
          <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="photo in org.defaultOrgImages | filter:{type:'photo'}" md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="1">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden;" class="attachment-tile no-outline" layout="row" layout-align="center center" ng-click="selectImage($event, photo)">
              <!-- <p class="m1">Loading...</p> -->
              <img attachment-src="{{ photo.path | ThumbnailFilter }}" default-src="images/no_img.png" style="cursor: pointer; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover;">
              <div id="overlay"></div>
            </div>
          </md-grid-tile>
        </md-grid-list>
      </div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.selectImage = function (ev, attachment) {
  if (attachment.type == 'photo' && attachment.path != $scope.org.defaultPhoto) {
    $scope.org.defaultPhoto = attachment.path;
    saveOrg();
  }
};
```

LESS

```
 #overlay {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the easiest way to accomplish this is to create a class in your CSS/LESS file like so:

```
.faded {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

And then all you have to do is append `faded` to the class value of the img you want to be faded.

This is generally the best and easiest way to change the opacity of multiple elements.

Comment: Yea, that isn't working because I am using `ng-repeat`.  I want all images to be "faded", and the one that is selected to be normal.  I have all of the images faded because of `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)`.  I want the selected image to have that removed.